# Plugging up a copper pipe via freezing

Tags: plumbing

When [freezing a copper pipe](https://youtu.be/ry4Qby_u41o?t=60) with a refrigerant, how does one know when the pipe has enough ice to "cork" the pipe and halt water flow?   Is there an indicator or a rule of thumb?

Comment: When the pipe spits it should be done.

Answer (score 5):

There are numerous water pipe freeze kits on the market. You can do a computer search for "water pipe freeze kits" or try "pipefreezekits.com". I however have never used a commercial freeze kit due to their cost. Instead of this method, I always used dry ice which was available at many ice plants. I have frozen water pipes up to 3" diameter in buildings. Since the size of the frozen pipe length is very short, and the discharge length was very long, there was never a chance for the pipe to burst.

How I did this was by using "shaved dry ice" put in a bath towel and wrapping the towel around the pipe using several outer wraps of the towel to act as insulation for the dry ice. Then you **wait for the pipe to show an ice layer on the pipe just past the towel**. As long as you maintain the dry ice the pipe will remain frozen. I once froze a 3" supply water line in a school where all the upstream valves would not close completely, including the utilities street shut off valve and kept it frozen for 10 hours.

Make sure that you protect any exposed skin and eyes with heavy work gloves and eye protection. The dry ice is unforgiving and will freeze skin and damage eyes in seconds.

Comment: I almost commented that you didn't actually answer the question, then I reread it and realized you did. I emphasized the actual answer part. The rest is excellent info, it just kinda hid the answer itself.

Comment: @SteveSether you hit it.  It provides a valve where none exists.

Answer (score 0):

Do a flow test.  Water will no longer flow.  Note that freezing water inside a copper pipe can easily damage it.  The technique in the video could conceivably be useful in some complicated emergency situation that justified the risk, but valves are put at convenient locations in water lines for a reason, and if you find you really need a valve somewhere, you're probably better off shutting off the main and installing one than freezing a pipe.

Also note that copper is an excellent thermal conductor, so if you're thinking of freezing a pipe "just enough" its likely that your plug won't last very long and the moment the layer of ice touching the pipe melts, the pipe is typically straight and smooth enough to allow the plug to move down the pipe.

Comment: @SteveSether yes I agree there could be careful techniques and situations in which an unconventional technique could be valuable.  Simply freezing a long enough section solid enough would likely crack the pipe though.  I would also imagine such a device could be built into a system risk free with the correct type of some other pipe.  Strong disadvantage that you would need extremely low temperatures to attempt to stop a pipe with even a little flow though.

Comment: @SteveSether I definitely don't see it as impossible, just limited, risky, challenging to do right in a failsafe and useful way and unnecessary in most cases.  An example application would be when you had a system you wanted to drain fail-safe on power or coolant failure like a nuclear reactor.  They use a plug of working fluid maintained by constant refrigeration and if the coolant loop fails the plug melts and drains the reactor.  I couldn't think of an example where this would be necessary in a common water system other than troubleshooting some complicated assembly.

Comment: @SteveSether water is not incompressible - it does have a bulk modulus of compressibility and that becomes significant at pressure. Just depends the pressures one is working at...